# One-to-many Association "org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream"

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I have problem with one-to-many mapping. If I don't add one-to-many mapping in the .xml file, everything works fine. However when I added one-to-many, I take this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/database/Hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.mkyong.common.App.main(App.java:14)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:610)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:631)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 11 of document  : Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "class". Nested exception: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "class".
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:601)
    ... 19 more
```

My Hibernate.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
     </property>

     <property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
           <value>/hibernate/User.hbm.xml</value>
           <value>/hibernate/Word.hbm.xml</value>
           <value>/hibernate/UserWord.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
      </property>   

    </bean>
</beans>
```

My User.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mkyong.stock.model.User" table="user" catalog="test">
        <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <set name="userWords" table="userword" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="USER_ID" not-null="true"></column>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.mkyong.stock.model.UserWord"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My Word.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mkyong.stock.model.Word" table="word" catalog="test">
        <id name="wordId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My UserWord.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mkyong.stock.model.UserWord" table="userword" catalog="test">
        <id name="userWordId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" class=com.mkyong.stock.model.User fetch="select">
            <column name="USER_ID" not-null="true"></column>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My User bean:

```
package com.mkyong.stock.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int userId;
    private Set<UserWord> userWords;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public Set<UserWord> getUserWord() {
        return userWords;
    }
    public void setUserWord(Set<UserWord> userWord) {
        this.userWords = userWord;
    }


}
```

My UserWrod bean:
    package com.mkyong.stock.model;

```
public class UserWord implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int userWordId;
    private User user;
    private Word word;

    public int getUserWordId() {
        return userWordId;
    }
    public void setUserWordId(int userWordId) {
        this.userWordId = userWordId;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Word getWord() {
        return word;
    }
    public void setWord(Word word) {
        this.word = word;
    }


}
```

My Word Bean:

```
package com.mkyong.stock.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

public class Word implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int wordId;
    private Set<UserWord> userWord;

    public int getWordId() {
        return wordId;
    }
    public void setWordId(int wordId) {
        this.wordId = wordId;
    }
    public Set<UserWord> getUserWord() {
        return userWord;
    }
    public void setUserWord(Set<UserWord> userWord) {
        this.userWord = userWord;
    }
}
```

And my database structure

create table user (
    ID int auto_increment,
    primary key(ID)
    );

```
create table word (
ID int auto_increment,
primary key(ID)
);

create table userword (
ID int auto_increment,
USER_ID int,
WORD_ID int,
primary key(ID)
);

alter table userword
add foreign key (USER_ID)
REFERENCES user(ID);

alter table userword
add foreign key (WORD_ID)
REFERENCES word(ID);
```

Thanks for helping,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `quotes` with class in  `UserWord.hbm.xml` file. Edit your  `UserWord.hbm.xml` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mkyong.stock.model.UserWord" table="userword" catalog="test">
        <id name="userWordId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" class="com.mkyong.stock.model.User" fetch="select">
            <column name="USER_ID" not-null="true"></column>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```